How to call functions hygenically from macros in Rust?
I have a macro in some module that calls a function:
mod a {
  mod b {
    fn foo(_: u32) {}

    macro_rules! bar {
      ( $x:expr ) => (foo($x))
    }
  }
}

This does not work from outside module a::b unless I import foo. Explicitly naming the module works in this case:
macro_rules! bar {
  ( $x:expr ) => (crate::a::b::foo($x))
}

However, this wouldn't work from outside the crate for an exported macro. I tried the following but it didn't work either:
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! bar {
  ( $x:expr ) => (::mycratename::a::b::foo($x))
}

Where mycratename is the name of the library in Cargo.toml.
[lib]
name = "mycratename"
crate-type = ["lib", "cdylib", "staticlib"]

At least it doesn't work when I try to use the macro from within the crate, I didn't try using it from outside. Is there a way to make it work from both within and outside the crate?

This is exactly what the reserved $crate meta variable is for.
It expands to crate within the defining crate and to ::crate_name outside of it.
See Also
Using $crate in Rust's procedural macros?


Note: It still expands to the regular ::crate_name even if you rename the crate on import, but it'll still correctly resolve the crate, though manually replacing the macro invocation with the expanded version will fail in this case.

Thanks for the footnote, didn't know of this particular sorcery!

"It still expands to the regular ::crate_name even if you rename the crate on import" - where are you bringing this from? It doesn't "expand" to anything, the compiler recognizes it and replaces it with the crate during name resolution.

@ChayimFriedman the HIR the compiler outputs. As well as cargo-expand.

I haven't actually checked this, but I believe the compiler does not expand to the name, only HIR pretty printing shows like it does (at least rust-analyzer does that).

If bar!() is a proc macro, it doesn't have access to the $crate metavariable.
In this case, there are two or three solutions:

Allow customizing what crate the macro emits, for example by providing a crate = <ident> possibility in the macro's input.
Always emit ::my_crate_name, but at your crate's top do extern crate self as my_crate_name;, which allows you to access the crate's items via ::my_crrate_name.
Provide a wrapper macro_rules!, that will call your macro and pass to it, in addition to the user's input, the $crate keyword. The proc macro will accept this as proc_macro::Ident, and put it in the output instead of ::my_crate_name.

3 is the best, but it is only available for function-like macros (no derives or attribute macros). Between 1 and 2, you can choose to do both, since 1 is also useful for users that rename your crate but 2 is more convenient.
